Even After calling "AddFontResource" api, that font not not available in application like MS PowerPoint
`For using new font in MS PowerPoint, we used following code. But, even after this code execute successfully, that newly added font not available in application like MS PowerPoint.
We called AddFontResource api font add font to environment.
We tried following C# code in our program.
private static BooleanResult InstallFont(string fontSource, string contentFontName)
        {
            _log.Info("Start installing "+ contentFontName);
            var userFontDir = Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                @"Microsoft\Windows\Fonts");
            var systemFontDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
            var fontPathInUserFontDir = Path.Combine(userFontDir, contentFontName);
            var fontPathInSystemFontDir = Path.Combine(systemFontDir, contentFontName);

            if (!File.Exists(fontPathInSystemFontDir)) 
            {
                try
                {
                    _log.Info("Coping " + contentFontName + " to " + fontPathInSystemFontDir);
                    File.Copy(fontSource, fontPathInSystemFontDir);
                    _log.Info("Font successfully Copied.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _log.Error($"Unexpected error when copying to system font dir", ex);
                }
            }

            try // Check Windows font folder again and add font resource
            {
                if (File.Exists(fontPathInSystemFontDir))
                {
                    _log.Info("Font file found: " + fontPathInSystemFontDir);
                    _log.Info("Adding " + fontPathInSystemFontDir + "to Env.");
                    var addFontResourceResult = AddFontResource(fontPathInSystemFontDir);
                    _log.Info("AddFontResource call returned: " + addFontResourceResult);
                    if (addFontResourceResult != 0)
                    {
                        _log.Info("AddFontResource call successful. Font added.");
                        return BooleanResult.DefaultResult;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error($"Unexpected error when adding font resource from system font dir", ex);
            }

            if (!File.Exists(fontPathInUserFontDir)) 
            {
                try
                {
                    _log.Info("copying " + contentFontName + " to " + fontPathInUserFontDir);
                    File.Copy(fontSource, fontPathInUserFontDir);
                    _log.Info("Font successfully Copied.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _log.Error($"Unexpected error when copying to user's font dir", ex);
                }
            }

            try // Check user's font folder again and add font resource
            {
                if (File.Exists(fontPathInUserFontDir))
                {
                    _log.Info("Font file found: " + fontPathInUserFontDir);
                    _log.Info("Adding " + fontPathInUserFontDir + "to Env.");
                    var addFontResourceResult = AddFontResource(fontPathInUserFontDir);
                    _log.Info("AddFontResource call returned: " + addFontResourceResult);
                    if (addFontResourceResult != 0)
                    {
                        _log.Info("AddFontResource call Successfull.");
                        return BooleanResult.DefaultResult;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error($"Unexpected error when adding font resource from user's font dir", ex);
            }

            return BooleanResult.FailResult("Font installation failed.");
        }

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);

We got following log also
enter image description here`
